Does Chinese gravestone belong to James Hudson Taylor?
My wife has an ancestor who died and was buried in China.  Their grave was desecrated and no longer exists, but apparently, this gravestone was found hidden under a church crawlspace, and was placed on a Wikipedia page relating to them, under a Creative Commons Licence

Can anyone here translate what is on the gravestone and confirm it belongs to James Hudson Taylor?

After comparing the documents, it has been confirmed that this is indeed the tombstone of James Hudson Taylor and his wife. The tombstone has undergone simple restoration and is currently stored in the Dexing Building of the Xuande Hall in Zhenjiang. enter link description here
The original inscription on the tombstone reads:
西一九三一年十二月勒石
先考、先妣戴公諱，德生府君、夫人合墓
男 存仁，媳 葛氏 敬立
他雖然死了卻因信仍就說話
A modern Chinese translation of the tombstone:
公元一九三一年十二月立碑
已故的父亲戴公，字德生，和已故的母亲合葬于此。
儿子存仁，儿媳葛氏 敬立此碑。
“他虽然死了，却因信仍然说话。”
Monument erected in December 1931 A.D.
My late father, Dai Gong (戴公), whose name was De Sheng (德生), was buried here together with my late mother.
The son, Cunren, and daughter-in-law, Ge, erected this monument.
‘and by it he being dead yet speaketh.’（KJV）

A friend of mine looked at this and here's her response:
"It says the son Chunren  and daughter in law Geshi, built/bought the graveyard for the parents Mr.&mrs Dai. There’s no way to confirm if it belongs to James.  The words at the bottom is from bible, I think it’s 'and by it he being dead yet speaketh.'"
"The gravestone was made in Dec. 1931."
